# Ruby - Web push notification with encrypted payload and registration_ids using gcm

Tags: ruby, push-notification, chrome-gcm

I want to send web push notification to my clients using gcm. There are many libraries for many languages to encrypt the payload. I use ruby [Webpush](https://github.com/zaru/webpush) gem for encrypt the payload and send the notification. As far as I see this library encrypts the payload as octet stream and sends the result with octet-stream content type to GCM. How can I include registration_ids in the request body?

Comment: the problem is that GCM doesn't understand octet-stream? it should be sent as json?

Comment: @Aleksey: GCM understands, but my problem is how to generate message payload and subscription ids array. Should I create a json containing the message object and the registeration_ids array and then encrypt that?

Comment: to be honest I never worked with push messages. I think you should just try  and see what happens.

Comment: The json approach seems logical. What is holding you back from trying/using this?

Comment: @maxpleaner: Because libraries I have seen their source code, send request body as octet-stream and I use these libraries to encrypt message payload...
See [PHP](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php/blob/master/src/WebPush.php#L197)
 or [Ruby](https://github.com/zaru/webpush/blob/master/lib/webpush/request.rb#L36)